# How to show the legends in pie chart of same or in just color while using achartengine library

Tags: android, achartengine

I am displaying pie charts in my application. 
I want to increase and decrease size of the legends in the pie chart. 
How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The color of the legend items is the same as the slice colors. You cannot change that.

Comment: what can be done if we have the source code of the achart engine library

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: yess we can change that by editing the source code, i was able to do it